# A procedure that tells how many Stamps I can buy with the pences I have

Tags: python

```
def stamps(p):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    x = (a, b, c)
    while p >= 5:
        p = p - 5
        a = a + 1
    else:    
        return p
        while p >= 2:
            p = p - 2
            b = b + 1
        else:    
            return p
            while p >= 1:
                p = p - 1
                c = c + 1
            else:    
                return p
#return x 
print stamps(8)
```

I keep getting a result of **3** instead of the intended **1** as if the code only reads the **first** update of the variable `p` in the first while loop.

The final idea is to get the result of `(1, 1, 1)` in the `x` variable, which means in this case that I can buy one stamp of 5 pence, one of 2 pence, and one of 1 pence, totalling the 8 pence I had.

Comment: FYI, when a `return` statement is executed, the code following it in the function will not be...

Comment: Hmm  makes sense, i though about changing the return statement with a print.. but i accuatlly i dont want those to be imprinted, only the x variable. So in order to make this work i can only erase the return's? or maybe chance to another statement?

Comment: You cannot bluntly remove all `return`s. How would the function know what value to return?

Comment: You could quickly explain the logic instead of use just code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a while loop, use a math base solution:

```
def stamps(p):
    price_a = 5
    price_b = 2
    price_c = 1 

    a = p // price_a
    p = p % price_a

    b = p // price_b
    p = p % price_b

    c = p // price_c #notice I don't % after this since price_c = 1 and you will always fit 1 in 1. 

    return (a,b,c)
#return x 
print stamps(8) # return (1,1,1)
```

If you think about it mathematically, what you want to do is find the number of times you can fit p into the price of the biggest stamp take the remainder and move on to the next stamp. So do a floor division using `//` (I'm assuming this is Python 2 based on your print statement) and then take a `%` to get the remainder of values.

Comment: i'm sure solving this mathematically is far better but i find a way more easier to think in a logic way. I will study your example of the code more and try to properly understand. Thanks!!

Comment: Just look up `floor division` and `modular` and things should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified version, I hope that this is desired results:

```
def stamps(p):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    while p >= 5:
        p = p - 5
        a = a + 1
    else:    

        while p >= 2:
            p = p - 2
            b = b + 1
        else:    

            while p >= 1:
                p = p - 1
                c = c + 1
    return (a,b,c)   # returning tuple of possible buying combinations

print stamps(8)
```

Try to change x to test it. As @DavidG said, after return, other code in function is not executed. You must return at the end, and need to return a,b, and c if you want to get those values. By returning `p` as in your code, you get the remaining of calculations.

Comment: your `x = (a,b,c)` here is not used here by the way, might want to suggest to OP on why and to remove it. Also it doesn't do what OP wants (which I assume is a pointer based variable.

Comment: I totally skipped that line while reading his code. Yeah, there is no need to create new variable just to return something, while you can return it directly. That's the point of ` return (a,b,c)`. Thanks @MooingRawr

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidG said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48930580#comment-84867123), I couldn't use a `return` statement in the loops because that would end the procedure, so I've changed the `return`'s for: `p = p` in order to keep the variable `p` updated for the next while loop.

Comment: Well, welcome to Stack Overflow then! As a new user you probably want to read the introductory [tour] some time, as it familiarizes you with the basics of Stack Overflow. One of the rules is: This Is Not A Forum, and so you must not 'follow up' and tell everybody what worked – we can see that because of the green check mark. But you are also allowed to add your own answer; just make sure to write it as one, not as if you are commenting on someone else's post.